# How to map 2 collections of different sizes using AutoMapper in C#?

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, automapper

Given that a source array has two elements, and the destination array has five elements, how to map them using automapper to make the destination array still have five elements after mapping?

For example:

```
class A {
  public int Id;
  public string Name;
}

class B {
  public int Id;
  public string Name;
  public DateTime? DateOfBirth;
}

var la = new List<A> {
  new A { 1, "A1" },
  new A { 2, "A2" }
};

var lb = new List<B> {
  new B { 1, "B1", new DateTime(2011, 2, 12) },
  new B { 2, "B2", new DateTime(2011, 3, 12) },
  new B { 3, "B3", new DateTime(2011, 4, 12) },
  new B { 4, "B4" },
  new B { 5, "B5" }
};
```

After mapping, something like

```
mapper.Map(la, lb);
```

I want to get such a lb:

```
{
  { 1, "A1", "2011-2-12" },
  { 2, "A2", "2011-3-12" },
  { 3, "B3", "2011-4-12" },
  { 4, "B4" },
  { 5, "B5" }
};
```

BUT, the lb I actually get looks like

```
{
  { 1, "A1", "2011-2-12" },
  { 2, "A2", "2011-3-12" }
}
```

How to do it? I think the key is how to create an appropriate automapper "profile"??? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show us the code with LINQ, without AutoMapper.

Answer (score 0):

You have `la` and `lb` and in our example, `la` has less elements than `lb`. So, you could

```
myResult.AddRange(lb.Skip(myResult.Count()));
```

presuming that the result of `Map` is enumerable.